# Microsoft RDP mixed mode

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, rdp

Ill currently have a win 2008 server and several Windows 7 desktop pc's with their own HDD connecting to the server.  I want to add some thin clients (no local HDD) to my existing environment connecting through RDP.
Is it possible to have a mixed environment (desktop pc and thin clients)
Do i have to keep something in mind when installing RDP into an existing environment?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. As long as the device supports Microsoft's RDP protocol, you can connect with any device to any MS Terminal Server.